# How to add additional assembly references to Linq2SQL DBML file?

Tags: visual-studio, linq-to-sql, or-designer

I have an DBML file in which I am using the IPAddress class (System.Net) to map a field in the database. Yet, I didnt find a way to have the DBML designer remember that it should add a "using System.Net" to the generated code.
Adding it manually works until the next time I save the file. Aint there a way to specify additional assemblies? I thought that specifying, like it already does for the predefined types, would work (like in "string (System.String)" but that just messes it up because it would insert literally "IPAddress (System.Net.IPAddress)" as type.

So, how do I get non-standard types into the O/R Designer so i can edit them too?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the fully classified name of the type (in this case System.Net.IPAddress) it actually works. Although of course it doesnt add the "using System.Net;" so one must have it referenced already.